# Object for holding amount of money

Tags: cocoa-touch

What object type is intended for storing an amount of money? I have a `UITextField` where the user can enter an amount of money in dollars, which I will convert to another currency, and I am wondering in which type to store the amount (`float`/`double` is not good for money), and what to select for the keyboard for that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using NSDecimalNumber. Additionally, you will want to use methods like:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByAdding:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber withBehavior:(id < NSDecimalNumberBehaviors >)behavior
```

over the more basic

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByAdding:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
```

Because one of the behaviors you can provide is:

> NSRoundBankers
>
> Round to the closest possible return value; when
>   halfway between two possibilities, return the possibility whose last
>   digit is even. In practice, this means that, over the long run,
>   numbers will be rounded up as often as they are rounded down; there
>   will be no systematic bias.

Of course using NSDecimal can be used as well, but I prefer the OO API of NSDecimalNumber over the C based API of NSDecimal.

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSDecimal or NSDecimalNumber they are precise, stored as base 10 numbers unlike float or double.

Answer (score 1):

you should do the following things

1. Set keyboard type decimal
2. Set the textfield in the keyboard accessory view (not compulsory )
3. Apply a regular expression that once the user have used the floating
   point (.) he will not be allowed to re-enter it.
4. On textfield done editing you may save it as NSDecimal

Answer (score 1):

I would use [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/)
 or NSDecimal, as they store in base10.

For the Keyboard, there is the [Decimal pad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits) .